# C++ Template with boolean tests for multiple types of data gets error of match

Tags: c++, templates, boolean, operators

I have been trying for quite some time now to create a template which accepts different types of data. A have a class Z2 defining the sign of an integer which is an enum class specified this way:

```
enum class Z2 {Plus, Minus};
```

I have to create a template called `mypow` which is of type Z2 for any type of data entered in it (float, int, Z2 types,etc), which will return the sign of the entered data in the format `Z2::Plus` or `Z2::Minus`.

My final try is this way:

```
template <class T> Z2 mypow(T a,unsigned int N){
  if (a==Z2::Plus || a>0){
    return Z2::Plus;
  }else if((a==Z2::Minus||a<0) && N%2==0){
    return Z2::Plus;
  }else{
    return Z2::Minus;
  }
}
```

However, each time I ran the code I got

```
error: no match for ‘operator>’ (operand types are ‘Z2’ and ‘int’)
if (a==Z2::Plus || a>0){
~^~
```

I am having trouble understanding this error message. So my questions are:

- 1) What does the error message mean ?
- 2) How should I do in order to have a template accepting conditions for multiple types of data ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enum class Z2 {Plus, Minus};` (rather than `enum Z2 {Plus, Minus};`) there is no implicit conversion from a Z2 and *int* (this is one of their goals)

So if you do

```
mypow<Z2>(Z2::Plus, 2);
```

you have the problem in `a>0` because there is no `operator>` for *Z2* nor implicit conversion from *Z2* to *int*

and when you do for instance

```
mypow<int>(1, 2);
```

you have a problem in `a==Z2::Minus` because there is no `operator==` on Z2 nor implicit conversion from *Z2* to *int*

---

If you want to mix *Z2* and *int* use a non class *enum* :

```
enum Z2 {Plus, Minus};

template <class T> Z2 mypow(T a,unsigned int N){
  if (a==Z2::Plus || a>0){
    return Z2::Plus;
  }else if((a==Z2::Minus||a<0) && N%2==0){
    return Z2::Plus;
  }else{
    return Z2::Minus;
  }
}

int main()
{
  Z2 a = mypow<Z2>(Plus, 2);
  Z2 b = mypow<int>(1, 2);

  return a == b;
}
```

Compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall e.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```